# how to remove html comments in php

Tags: php, html, comments

I am trying to remove any comments embedded with the html file

```
$data= file_get_contents($stream); <br>
$data = preg_replace('<!--*-->', '', $data); <br>
echo $data;
```

I am still ending up with all the comments < !- bla bla bla --> 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see those links on the right >>

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegExp to strip HTML comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084741/regexp-to-strip-html-comments)

Answer (score 13):

```
// Remove unwanted HTML comments
function remove_html_comments($content = '') {
    return preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $content);
}
```

As you can read here : https://davidwalsh.name/remove-html-comments-php

Answer (score 5):

I know lots of answers are already posted. I have tried many but for me this regular expression works for multi line (in my case 40 line of comments)  HTML comments removal.

```
$string = preg_replace("~<!--(.*?)-->~s", "", $string);
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

The below regex will remove HTML comments, but will keep conditional comments.

```
<!--(?!<!)[^\[>].*?-->
```

Comment: `strip_tags` strips all the tags, not just comments.

Comment: @NedBatchelder, Thanks to advice, i read fast the question and didn't pay attention about this. I've done an edit.

Comment: `strip_tags` always strips comments, but you can specify WHAT tags to strip.  Specfy something that's not in HTML, and you strip only comments.

Comment: @ghoti: read the docs more closely, `strip_tags` takes an *allowable_tags* argument.

Comment: should the $data need to converted to a string before it can be edited?

Comment: @NedBatchelder - that's what I'm saying.  If you specify all HTML tags in *allowable_tags*, `strip_tags` will still remove comments.  That was also in the docs, in case you missed it.  It's the first **Note** under the *allowable_tags* description.

Comment: Ah - my previous comment had a brain fart, and implied reverse logic for allowable_tags.  Sorry 'bout that.  :)

Comment: @ShawonMd, I don't think so, you can use directly.

Comment: Even better, add the delimiters at beginning and end. Also use the s flag (PCRE_DOTALL) to match the '.' to newlines as well. End result something like this: `preg_replace("~<!--(?!<!)[^\[>].*?-->~s", "", $string);` This is what I use for my processing.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it without using regular expression:

```
function strip_comments($html)
{
    $html = str_replace(array("\r\n<!--", "\n<!--"), "<!--", $html);
    while(($pos = strpos($html, "<!--")) !== false)
    {
        if(($_pos = strpos($html, "-->", $pos)) === false)
            $html = substr($html, 0, $pos);
        else
            $html = substr($html, 0, $pos) . substr($html, $_pos+3);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`s/<!--[^>]*?-->//g`

switch up regular expression

Comment: You actually need `[^>]*?` to match as little as possible or you will remove everything from the very first `<!--` to the very last `-->` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regular expressions are very difficult to corral into doing what you want here.
2. To match arbitrary text in a regex, you need `.*`, not just `*`.  Your expression is looking for `<!-`, followed by zero or more `-` characters, followed by `-->`.

Comment: My target html has comments on multiline..one line comments are working fine...how do i fix multiline comments?

Comment: You actually need `.*?` to match as little as possible or you will remove everything from the very first `<!--` to the very last `-->` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex for such a task. Regex can fail for unexpected characters.
Instead, I would do something that is safe, like this:

```
$linesExploded = explode('-->', $html);
foreach ($linesExploded as &$line) {
    if (($pos = strpos($line, '<!--')) !== false) {
        $line = substr($line, 0, $pos);
    }
}
$html = implode('', $linesExploded);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should do this way:

```
$str = "<html><!-- this is a commment -->OK</html>";
$str2 = preg_replace('/<!--.*-->/s', '', $str);
var_dump($str2);
```

Comment: I am parsing a page with file get contents...with this code i still end up with all the comments

Comment: Edited (removed backslashes), i tried (in my case)  it's works.