# Regex to avoid stripping IE conditional tags

Tags: php, regex

I am using a Regex in PHP strip my HTML comments.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/Uis', '', $html);
```

But, I dont want the regex to strip out conditional IE TAGS which I have

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><html class="ie6 no-js">
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

**EDIT:**
For convenience, I have added related HTML code here:
http://pastebin.com/dPGHHXjU
(OR)
here: https://regex101.com/r/yS8zM6/1

Thanks in advance

Comment: `preg_replace('/<!--([^<>]*)-->/Uis', '', $html);`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: your solution does not remove any comment bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this one](https://regex101.com/r/yS8zM6/6):

```
<!--(?!\[).*?-->
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: but your regex works with small code. (the one which you tested). What should I do? 
here is the code: https://regex101.com/r/yS8zM6/1

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from a different post:

```
$html = preg_replace('~<!--(?!<!)[^\[>].*?-->~s','', $html);
```

This regex works well. (But I am not sure of what it does)

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337360/1163642  (A comment from that answer by Allen Pestaluky)

I have added a demonstration here: https://regex101.com/r/yS8zM6/2