# How do you test the content of a div or other element in enzyme/mocha/chai?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I'm trying to verify that the content of a div matches what I'm expecting. What I have is:

```
expect(wrapper.find('div.title').text().to.equal('A New Day');
```

However, this isn't working for me. Is this possible in enzyme/chai/mocha?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can easily setup chai-enzyme https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme which is very great for things like this. Now you can use:

`expect(wrapper.find('.title')).to.have.text('A New Day')`

Answer (score 3):

The property you are looking for is `textContent`

`expect(wrapper.find('div.title').textContent).to.equal('A New Day');`

If you are using chai, which it sounds like you are, you can add a custom assertion.  Here is the one I wrote for our project.

```
// Asserts that the the DOM Element has the expected text
// E.G. expect(myDOMNode).to.have.text('the text');
const text = Assertion.addMethod('text', function(value) {
  this.assert(
    this._obj.textContent === value,
    'expected #{exp} === #{act}',
    'expected #{exp} !== #{act}',
    this._obj.textContent,
    value
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much React/JSX you have in your text content, it might be mangled to make simple matching fail:

```
// wrapper.text() 
<!-- react-text: 28 -->A <!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 29 -->New<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 30 --> Day<!-- /react-text -->
```

So if you must test that directly, you can strip them out like so:

```
expect(wrapper.text().replace(/<!--[^>]*-->/g, "")).toContain("A New Day");
```

The regex came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1084759/1004027), which warns against regex html.  But react-node comments are relatively straightforward.

---

p.s. testing props instead is usually a better idea; react's html rendering is already unit-tested by facebook