# How to remove html comments from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

So, I have a javascript string which is actually some html markup assigned to it.

Now, I want to remove all the html comments and its content from the string, ie all the occurrences of the opening comment tag and closing comment tag; along with the comment inside in it.

So I want to remove all occurences of

```
<!-- some comment -->
```

Please note I want ' some comment ' removed as well...

Can someone help me with the regex to replace this...

Thanks

Comment: Maybe convert it to a DOM node? Then loop through the ndoe elements, and remove all nodes whose type matches a comment?

Comment: Using Regular Exprssions, what if `<!-- some comment -->` is within a variable content `var text = '<!-- some comment -->';`?

Comment: `text = text.replace(/<\!--.+?-->/sg,"")` !Don't forget to add `s` and `g` modifiers

Comment: maybe this helps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but)

Comment: I think this was allready answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084741/regexp-to-strip-html-comments)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

like this

```js
var str = `<div></div>
<!-- some comment -->
<p></p>
<!-- some comment -->`
str = str.replace(/<\!--.*?-->/g, "");
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Thanks... this regex is working... I also tried using split and join on particular comments and it was working but I preferred to do it with regex and on all comments... Thanks, and also accepted because it's vanilla javascript...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this RegEx to replace the text between `<!--` and `-->`

```
/(\<!--.*?\-->)/g
```

Check the snippet below

```js
var string = '<!-- some comment --><div><span>Some Content</span></div><!-- some other comment -->';

var reg = /(\<!--.*?\-->)/g;
string = string.replace(reg,"");

console.log(string);
```

Comment: What is the use of `i` modifier in your code? Better you can add `s` modifier also.

Comment: Why the extra parenthesis (capture group around the entire regex)?

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for like this.

```js
      var content = jQuery('body').html();
    alert(content.match(/<!--.*?-->/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <!-- some comment -->
</body>
</html>
```