# Regex lookahead why

Tags: php, regex, pcre

For PCRE, what's the difference between the following two regexes?
`(?=<!--)([\s\S]*?-->)` and
`(<!--[\s\S]*?-->)`

The first one is to match *HTML comments* mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084741/regexp-to-strip-html-comments#comment59274030_29194283)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two patterns will match the same thing.  Here is an explanation of the first pattern:

```
(?=<!--)         assert that what immediately follows is <!--
([\s\S]*?-->)    then capture everything, across lines if necessary,
                 until reaching the first -->
```

The second pattern does not use lookaheads, but rather just matches a single HTML comment:

```
(<!--[\s\S]*?-->)
```

Again, this pattern will match across lines.

I would expect both patterns to have a similar performance.  What you choose would depend on which performs better for your data, the tool you use (not all regex engines support lookarounds), and which pattern you find easier to read.

Comment: Output array?  I think maybe you forgot to show us code.

Comment: I was just wondering why `(<!--[\s\S]*?-->)` is not the first choice to match HTML comments, was thinking if the lookahead thing is a Regex idiom or a common way of matching certain patterns. But now you tell me that the two regexes match exactly the same stuff and could only be the performance a difference, so I get it very well. Thanks.

Comment: @Jarod The major functional difference between the two pattern is that a lookahead _asserts_, but does not _consume_.  So in the first pattern, the lookahead `(?=<!--)` does not actual consume the pattern, whereas in the second pattern matches the entire string.

Comment: You can reduce the step count for regex patterns by minimizing/eliminating capture groups and lookarounds.  Unless I am misunderstanding, this task doesnt require either.

Comment: @revo That would have been my guess as well, as the lookbehind might be prone to backtracking etc.

Comment: There are some pre-scan optimizations which PCRE does if a Regular Expression starts with a literal character. If a known starting point exists, it causes a failing match to happen in a second.